# How can I use GetType() for CheckBox?

Tags: .net, c++

I'm currently working with C++ and .NET 1.1 (Don't ask...), and I'd like to check if an object is a CheckBox.

GetType seems the obvious choice, but for some reason I can't get it to work like I want. Using `GetType()` on an instance of a CheckBox works fine, but trying to use `Type::GetType("System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox")` does not.

The following code will throw an exception on the second line, despite what should (in my mind at least) be a perfectly formatted string being fed to `GetType(temp)`. If I replace `temp` with, for example, `"System.Int32"` instead, it works fine as well.

```
String* temp = (this->checkBox1->GetType())->ToString();
temp = (System::Type::GetType(temp))->ToString();
```

Why is this? =)

I can imagine several different ways to work around this of course, but it just bugs me that I can't get this to work the way I think it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using C++ with managed extensions.  If so try the following

```
if (this->checkBox1->GetType() == __typeof(CheckBox)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'll confess I have no idea what that means, but it works like a charm. =)

Comment: @Jon, the `__typeof` operator will return a `Type` object for the given named value.  Instances of `Type` are directly comparable so `GetType() == __typeof` is really asking "Is the runtime type of `checkBox1` the type `CheckBox`?"

Comment: Yeah, I understand what the code does, I just don't understand why it needs to be this way, but I'm guessing I should read up a bit on managed extensions? =)

Comment: `GetType()` is the .NET way of retrieving type metadata at runtime.  If you want the C++-specific way to this, use `dynamic_cast` and check that the result of the cast is non-null (i.e. `if (dynamic_cast<CheckBox>(this->checkBox1) != 0)` ... ).  Note that this isn't exactly the same as the .NET version since `dynamic_cast` checks for type compatibility instead of type equality.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the type you're loading is in mscorlib or the calling assembly, you need to give the fully qualified assembly name, including keys etc. See the [docs for `Type::GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for more details.

If you know the assembly ahead of time, [`Assembly::GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) is probably a simpler 
approach.

EDIT: I'm assuming you don't know the compile type at compile time, only as a string. Otherwise use Jared's answer :)

Comment: I believe the OP is using C++ with managed extensions so they'll need to use `::` vs. `.` for static access.  Example `Assembly::GetType`